# how to get value of span on image click

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I want to get span value my code is below.  All i want is get span value with class="hideme" when i click any of image. Im using html5 jquerymobile phonegap_v2.0 framework Xcode_v4.3

css code:

```
.hideme{
diplay:none;
}
```

html code:

```
  <ol id='ulist' data-role='listview' data-filter='true'>
         <li>

         <a href='#' rel="external" data-mini="true">John<span id='id1'  class="hideme" >1</span></a>
             <div data-role="field" style="float: right;margin-top: -30px;padding-right: 4%;">
             <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/info.png" alt="info"/>
              <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/session.png" alt="session"/>
              <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/prospclient.png" alt="Prospect Client"/>
             <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/delete.png" alt="delete"/>
             </div>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a href='#' rel="external" data-mini="true">Carmen<span id='id2' class="hideme" >2</span></a>
             <div data-role="field" style="float: right;margin-top: -30px;padding-right: 4%;">
                 <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/info.png" alt="info"/>
                 <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/session.png" alt="session"/>
                 <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/prospclient.png" alt="Prospect Client"/>
                 <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/delete.png" alt="delete"/>
             </div>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a href='#' rel="external" data-mini="true">Julia<span id='id3' class="hideme" >3</span></a>
             <div data-role="field" style="float: right;margin-top: -30px;padding-right: 4%;">
                 <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/info.png" alt="info"/>
                 <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/session.png" alt="session"/>
                 <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/prospclient.png" alt="Prospect Client"/>
                 <img data-mini="true" src="icons/ios/delete.png" alt="delete"/>
             </div>
         </li>
    </ol>
```

how to do in javascript or jquery

Comment: What have you tried? Those are two different problems: 1: assign a click event to an element. 2: read the value (=text/html?) of an element. Both are pretty easy in JQuery, so if you look at them seperately, you'll find hundreds of examples which you only need to combine.

Comment: none of the two answers working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span elements don't have a "value". If you're asking how to get the text content of the span contained within the same `<li>` element as a clicked `<img>` element then you can do this with jQuery:

```
$("#ulist img").click(function() {
    var spanContent = $(this).closest("li").find("span.hideme").text();
});
```

If you're asking how to get the `id` attribute, use `.attr("id")` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: function GetId(){
             var spanContent = $("#ulist img").closest("li").find("span.hideme").text();
                alert(spanContent);
            } is working for me but it is giving all values from all spans how i get only the clicked li span text

Comment: You need to use `$(this).closest...` rather than `$("#ulist img").closest)` _within a click event handler_ for the image element(s), where jQuery will set `this` to the clicked image element. As shown in my answer.

Comment: i need only selected li span text

Comment: your code giving me array of all span's text

Comment: You tried the code from my answer exactly as shown? You didn't just take part of it like in your first comment?

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
 $(function() {
              $('li').click(function() {
                 var list_item = $(this);
                  var Id = list_item.find('span.hideme').text();
                   alert(Id);
                            });
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this,

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W33rK/

```
​$('img')​.click(function(){
   var span = $(this).parents('li').find('span.hideme').text();    
   //alert(span)
})​
```

Comment: i dont know but its not working can you check your code in jsfiddle. no alert working

Comment: im not good at jquery. do i have to give onlcick event in every image?

Comment: there is no jquerymobile framwork in jsfiddle how do i test my script